# I cannot edit my crontab in Ubuntu after saving the file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

**Edited**

Why would the below command cause `crontab -e` to show permission denied errors?

`/bin/sh /var/www/ers-api-proxy/backup.sh 1> /var/www/ers-api-proxy/log.txt 2> /var/www/ers-api-proxy/err.txt`

Crontab works fine for me until I run this command.

When it stopped working originally, I restored my DO droplet and it began working again. Then when I ran the above command for a second time the same issue happened again?

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01:/var/www/ers-api-proxy# EDITOR=pico

root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01:/var/www/ers-api-proxy# crontab -e
pico: Permission denied
crontab: "pico" exited with status 1

root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01:/var/www/ers-api-proxy# export EDITOR

root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01:/var/www/ers-api-proxy# crontab -e
pico: Permission denied
crontab: "pico" exited with status 1

root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01:/var/www/ers-api-proxy# sudo crontab -e
/usr/bin/sensible-editor: Permission denied
crontab: "/usr/bin/sensible-editor" exited with status 1

root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01:/var/www/ers-api-proxy# export EDITOR=/usr/bin/sensible-editor

root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01:/var/www/ers-api-proxy# sudo crontab -e
/usr/bin/sensible-editor: Permission denied
crontab: "/usr/bin/sensible-editor" exited with status 1

root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01:/var/www/ers-api-proxy# crontab -l
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0 5 * * 2 /bin/sh /var/www/ers-api-proxy/backup.sh 1> /var/www/ers-api-proxy/log.txt 2> /var/www/ers-api-proxy/err.txt
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01:/var/www/ers-api-proxy#
```

**Edit**: On a side note, I just re-logged into SSH and I'm getting this error as well which I feel wasn't showing before (but not 100%)

```
-bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

`/bin/sh` is also what I added to my cronjob, could this be related?

**Edit 2**: It actually looks like it's multiple commands that are no longer working for me, even though I'm logged in as root. Here is what's happening when I try to run my shell script now (which was working fine before)

```
tar (child): gzip: Cannot exec: Permission denied
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: Looks as if you removed the executable permission bit (`x`) from files in `/bin` and `/usr/bin`

Comment: What permissions should I set it back to? I'm not sure how I would've done that as I didn't change any permissions. It literally started after saving the cron, and trying to run the cron command manually to make sure it wouldn't dish out errors. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: `chmod a+x /bin/* /usr/bin/*`. However, if you cleared the `s` bit from some commands, which require it, it is probably easier for you to reinstall.

Comment: This actually wasn't the issue, I restored my droplet and I noticed the permissions where the same yet it started working again. It's not until I run `/bin/sh /var/www/ers-api-proxy/backup.sh 1> /var/www/ers-api-proxy/log.txt 2> /var/www/ers-api-proxy/err.txt` that it stops working for me?

Comment: So the problem is probably inside `backup.sh`.

Comment: If the permissions are correct, then your backup script may have remounted / with noexec. You'll need to check for any "mount -o remount,..." commands in the script, and comment them out until you can verify them.